<App> not responding pop up tempo
I often use Unison to sync some folders on my network (4 machines).
When the machines are connected on the Ethernet wired network, speed is fine.
But when I'm away from home I use a small Huawey 4G router and the NFS speed is terrible.
So my Unison sometimes get stuck transmitting large files over a slow link.
After a couple of seconds, the pop-up shows asking if I want to wait or kill the app.
See the picture.
I would like to change the delay before the pop-up shows in order to be safe and not kill my app by accident.
I was unable to find where and how it is defined.
I'm currently running 22.04.4 LTS using kernel 6.8.0-40-generic and Gnome on Wayland.
Many thanks in advance for your help.
Have a nice and bright day !


I get the same on v22.04 (sometimes) when there is an update. I don't stress about it. It goes of its own accord once the update has commenced and doesn't require any intervention on my part. I have no idea what drives it and it doesn't affect any user experience or prevent the operation.

Hello,I actually found an answer to my question in the suggestions offered on the right hand panel when asking. I overlooked them, sorry. The solution is to change Gnome mutter setting : gsettings set org.gnome.mutter check-alive-timeout 120000 (here set to 2 minutes (120 seconds)...

I actually found an answer to my question in the suggestions offered on the right hand panel when asking.
I overlooked them, sorry.
The solution is to change Gnome mutter setting :
gsettings set org.gnome.mutter check-alive-timeout 120000
(here set to 2 minutes (120 seconds)...
